# vlc installation problem

Tags: vlc

While installing VLC player on ubuntu 14.04 I recieve the following error:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:

vlc: Depends: vlc-nox (= 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1) but 2.1.6-0ubuntu14.04.1 is to be installed
     Depends: libc6 (>= 2.15) but 2.19-0ubuntu6.6 is to be installed
     Depends: libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1) but 2.5.2-1ubuntu2.4 is to be installed
     Depends: libgcc1 (>= 1:4.1.1) but 1:4.9.1-0ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtcore4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libqtgui4 (>= 4:4.8.0) but 4:4.8.5+git192-g085f851+dfsg-2ubuntu4 is to be installed
     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 4.6) but 4.8.2-19ubuntu1 is to be installed
     Depends: zlib1g (>= 1:1.2.3.3) but 1:1.2.8.dfsg-1ubuntu1 is to be installed
```

Comment: try `sudo apt-get -f install` and then try install vlc again

Comment: i tried but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

It means that you haven't updated a lot of system packages in a long time, or you are not installing the vlc package from the repository.

Run

`sudo apt-get update`

and then run

`sudo apt-get upgrade`

and then run

`sudo apt-get install vlc`

If you still face issues run

`sudo apt-get -f install`

Comment: it is not working even after using ur suggestions, kindly help